# Difference between известный and знаменитый?

Tags: перевод

I would like to know the difference in the usage of the two words that translate "famous": известный and знаменитый. Can I use them interchangeably both for famous people and famous things (museums, cities, book, quotations...). For example, if I need to translate "Michelangelo was a famous sculptor" I'd better choose the first, the second, or it doesn't matter? I need this info as regards a written text, not an oral context.. 
thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Знаменитый" has a greater degree of fame than "известный".

"Знаменитый" is "famous, celebrated, illustrious, outstanding, superlative", "известный" is "well-known, known".

> знаменитый артист – famous actor, celebrated actor
>
> знаменитая книга учёного ­- famous book of the scientist
>
> Нижний Новгород знаменит своей промышленной ярмаркой ­- Nizhny Novgorod is famous for its fair

but

> известный художник — well-known painter
>
> известный учёный — noted scientist
>
> известный чем-либо — noted for something
>
> он известен своей честностью — he is known for his honesty; he has a name for honesty

As for Michelangelo, he was definitely "знаменитый скульптор".